# stripping the zeros in csv with python

Tags: python, csv

Hello I have a csv file and I need to remove the zero's with python:

Column 6, column 5 in python is defaulted to 7 digits.  with this

```
AFI12001,01,C-,201405,P,0000430,2,0.02125000,US,60.0000
AFI12001,01,S-,201404,C,0001550,2,0.03500000,US,30.0000
```

I need to remove the zeros in front then I need to add a zero or zeros to make sure it has 4 digits total

so I would need it to look like this:

```
AFI12001,01,C-,201405,P,0430,2,0.02125000,US,60.0000
AFI12001,01,S-,201404,C,1550,2,0.03500000,US,30.0000
```

This code adds the zero's

```
import csv

new_rows = []
with open('csvpatpos.csv','r') as f:
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
for row in csv_f:
new_row = ""
col = 0
print row
for x in row:
col = col + 1
if col == 6:
if len(x) == 3:
x = "0" + x
new_row = new_row + x + ","
print new_row
```

However, I'm having trouble removing the zeros in front.

Comment: are all the numbers at the same index?

Comment: BTW: correct indentions to make your code readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do this in several steps with `.lstrip()`, then finding the resulting string length, then adding on `4-len(s)` 0s to the front.  However, I think it's easier with `regex`.

```
with open('infilename', 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for row in reader:
        stripped_value = re.sub(r'^0{3}', '', row[5])
```

Yields

```
0430
1550
```

In the regex, we are using the format `sub(pattern, substitute, original)`.  The pattern breakdown is:

```
'^' - match start of string
'0{3}' - match 3 zeros
```

You said all the strings in the 6th column have 7 digits, and you want 4, so replace the first 3 with an empty string.

---

**Edit**: If you want to replace the rows, I would just write it out to a new file:

```
with open('infilename', 'r') as infile, open('outfilename', 'w') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in reader:
        row[5] = re.sub(r'^0{3}', '', row[5])
        writer.writerow(row)
```

---

**Edit2**: In light of your newest requests, I would recommend doing the following:

```
with open('infilename', 'r') as infile, open('outfilename', 'w') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in reader:
        # strip all 0's from the front
        stripped_value = re.sub(r'^0+', '', row[5])
        # pad zeros on the left to smaller numbers to make them 4 digits
        row[5] = '%04d'%int(stripped_value)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Given the following numbers,

```
['0000430', '0001550', '0013300', '0012900', '0100000', '0001000']
```

this yields

```
['0430', '1550', '13300', '12900', '100000', '1000']
```

Comment: Hi Bill, this actually might work. Do I need to write to the file as well to replace the data?

Comment: It doesn't look like it actually working.  Its keeping the zeros for some reason. But it looks like its going down the right track.

Comment: Nick are you still having problems with this?

Comment: Not working just yet.  It seems to be adding zeros to numbers that are longer than 4 digits. 

AFI12001,01,W-,201405,P,0560,2,0.01375000,US,55.0000

AFI12001,01,17,201404,C,0013300,2,0.15625000,US,21.0000

AFI12001,01,17,201404,C,0013400,2,0.06250000,US,30.0000

AFI12001,01,17,201404,C,0013500,2,0.03125000,US,10.0000

AFI12001,01,17,201404,C,0013700,2,0.01563000,US,25.0000

AFI12001,01,17,201404,P,0012800,2,0.04688000,US,38.0000

AFI12001,01,17,201404,P,0012900,2,0.10938000,US,5.0000

Comment: Are you sure this is for my solution? This `re.sub` call will not add any zeros. It will only replace 3 leading zeros from strings.  Do you want it do more? Specifically, 1.) are all your numbers 7 digits? 2.) do you want to remove all leading zeros from numbers (i.e. 0013300 -> 13300)?

Comment: Hi Bill, so basically I have to remove all the zeros in front of the digits that are longer than 4.  However, I need to add the zero in front of the digits if the number is 4 or less. So yes the second part is what I need to see.  But I'm not sure how to get that. So the code is correct but I need it to look like your example: 0013300 -> 13300

Comment: This is odd.  I'm getting the following error:  row[5] = '%04d'% int(stripped_value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'PSTRIK'

Comment: This means the value you want stripped is not always in the same column.  You should think about exactly what your problem is, and how your data is formatted and as a new question.

Comment: I need to have the script ignore the first column. Because its the title of each row.  How do have it ignore the first row?

Answer (score 2):

Convert the column to an int then back to a string in whatever format you want.

```
row[5] = "%04d" % int(row[5])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`lstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lstrip) and [`zfill()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.zfill) methods. Like this:

```
with open('input') as in_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(in_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        stripped_data = row[5].lstrip('0')
        new_data = stripped_data.zfill(4)
        print new_data
```

This prints:

```
0430
1550
```

The line:

```
stripped_data = row[5].lstrip('0')
```

gets rid of all the zeros on the left. And the line:

```
new_data = stripped_data.zfill(4)
```

fills the front with zeros such that the total number of digits are 4.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How would I add all the data plus this to another csv file? Would I just use the write command? In addition, this is adding zero's to blank fields, is there a way around that?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep last 4 chars

```
columns[5] = columns[5][-4:]
```

example

```
data = '''AFI12001,01,C-,201405,P,0000430,2,0.02125000,US,60.0000
AFI12001,01,S-,201404,C,0001550,2,0.03500000,US,30.0000'''

for row in data.splitlines():

    columns = row.split(',')

    columns[5] = columns[5][-4:]

    print ','.join(columns)
```

result

```
AFI12001,01,C-,201405,P,0430,2,0.02125000,US,60.0000
AFI12001,01,S-,201404,C,1550,2,0.03500000,US,30.0000
```

---

EDIT:

code with `csv` module - not `data` to simulate file.

```
import csv

with open('csvpatpos.csv','r') as f:

    csv_f = csv.reader(f)

    for row in csv_f:

        row[5] = row[5][-4:]

        print row[5] # print one element

        #print ','.join(row) # print full row
        print row # print full row
```

Comment: I getting columns are undefined, and there are tons of rows with different data after that.

Comment: See new example with module `csv` and without `data` simulating file.

Comment: This actually worked.  However, its adding zeros to blank columns. Do you know how to get around that?